# Gamepad in multiplayer games

Tags: wii-u

When playing multiplayer in the following games, can you use the gamepad to control a character just like a regular Wii Remote?

- Mario Kart 8
- Super Mario 3D World
- New Super Mario Bros. U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes for Mario Kart 8 and Super Mario 3D World. NO for New Super Mario Bros U: in NSMBU, you cannot use the gamepad to control a character when playing multiplayer - you have to use Wiimotes or the Pro controllers only to control characters (the gamepad in multiplayer NSMBU works only in "Boost mode" to give other players boosts). Note that in single player NSMBU you can use the gamepad to control your character.

Answer (score 0):

Playing multiplayer on Mario Kart 8 allows you to use the gamepad to control the character. The nice thing about the gamepad when using it with Mario Kart 8 is that you can switch between using the joystick or using the tilt control which mimics the Wii Remote. The gamepad can also be used to control your character in New Super Mario Bros. U. I'm not sure about Super Mario 3D World since I have to play that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about the tablet looking thing, then yes.

Mario kart and Mario bros u both mirror the screen exactly so playing on it vs the Wii mote won't offer you any advantage.  You will have to check on 3d world, but I think it is the same there as well.